# Is it a good idea to have a business model around 1 app - multiple users or 1 user per app?

Tags: django, heroku, business-intelligence

I have a competition management application that I will be hosting with heroku. Every user of the application would need certain things like an integrated registration store which also plug in the entries so that the registrants can be judged and access to all of their information after the competition to provide results. I dont know how to build this around a profile system that lets you manage your competitions so I was thinking just duplicate the app upon request with a subdomain name for each new event that wants to use it. Is this a bad idea? Should I bite the bullet and figure out how to do the whole profile thing so its one app? - if so please point me in the right direction of how. I am using django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for multiple app per User, Just one app is enough and define your model something like ...!

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    result = models.IntegerField()

class Registration(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    competition = models.ForeignKey(Completition)
```

Just do event `Registration` in `localhost.com:8000/competition/event_name` or Do with your own logic here.